# Calculating accurate cpu usage per task in assembly

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly, inline-assembly

I've a multi-task program written in C++ and I want to calculate CPU usage for each of threads in sub second basis (may be 100 ms)
as you may know /proc/stat or something like that didn't have accuracy for that resolution of time.

I want to know is there a way to calculate clock cycles consumed for each thread in assembly or C/C++?

Comment: "Accurate" isn't really possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time sources in x86 processors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229644/time-sources-in-x86-processors)

Comment: So, how do you know what time was spent in what thread, and how much time was spent in some other thread (e.g. in the "let's unpack this network packet that just came in" or "let's zero the memory of that page the OS just got freed", etc, etc)

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: Clock cycles, or clocking counts per instruction, is processor dependent.  Which processor are you using?

Comment: Clock cycles per instruction also depend in the data cache (whether the needed data exists in the cache or not), as well as the instruction pipeline and internal blocks in the processor (such as barrel shifters and ALUs).  BTW, in modern processors, clock cycle times may be measured in nanoseconds or microseconds.

Comment: Are you using multiple CPUs or one CPU with multiple cores?  There may be differences like multiple cores can share a high speed databus (internal to the processor) whereas multiple CPUs (processors) may have to use an external databus between the processors.  A good example is threads running on the main CPU and a graphics processor.

Comment: Lastly, your benchmarking may be influenced by other activities in your system.  Your threads may get interrupted and paged out for other higher priority activies (or other activities at the same priority).  Your OS may be running your threads on the same core and using the other core(s) to run other programs (such as music playter).  Research benchmarking and performance measurements first.

Comment: thanks thomas. really I'm using one multi-core Intel X86 CPU and want to measure how much time spend in each of my threads. I know OS my interfere and measurement may be differ from time to time

Comment: _as you may know /proc/stat or something like that didn't have accuracy for that resolution of time_ ... sorry, I don't know. It counts in jiffies which is well into the sub second range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Linux 2.6.12 and glibc 2.4, you can use [clock_gettime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with a clock of type **CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID** to get realiable timing information