# Avoid blinking/flickering when drawing graphics in 8086 real-mode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm new to Assembly Language 8086. I'm using masm611. I am making dinosaur game (Google Chrome offline game). The more i draw the more screen starts blinking. I've tried everything but can't find anything. code compiles perfectly without error.
Here is the code

```
MainLoop:
    ;call clearRegisters
    mov ah,01h
    int 16h
    mov bh,ah
    mov bl,0

    mov al,0
    mov ah,0Ch
    int 21h

    cmp bh,12h
    je Exit

    call SelectScreen

    mov ax,dinoObj.x
    mov x,ax
    mov ax,dinoObj.y
    mov y,ax

    call clearRegisters
    call DrawBackground

    call clearRegisters
    call drawDinoBase
    call clearRegisters

    call drawDino
    call clearRegisters
jmp MainLoop`
```

SelectScreen funtion is as follows

```
SelectScreen proc
    mov ah,0
    mov al,12h
    int 10h
    Terminate:
    ret
SelectScreen Endp`
```

Snippet of DrawDino function

```
drawDino proc
mov ax,y
mov tempY,ax
mov cx,8
outer1:
    push cx
    mov ax,x
    mov tempX,ax
    mov cx,20
    inner1:
        push cx
        mov ah,0ch
        mov al,10
        mov cx,tempX
        mov dx,tempY
        int 10h
        inc tempX
        pop cx
    loop inner1
    inc tempY
    pop cx
    loop outer1

    mov ax,y
    add ax,8
    mov tempY,ax
    mov cx,12
    outer2:
        push cx
        mov ax,x
        mov tempX,ax
        mov cx,38
        inner2:
            push cx
            mov ah,0ch
            mov al,10
            mov cx,tempX
            mov dx,tempY
            int 10h
            inc tempX
            pop cx
        loop inner2
        inc tempY
        pop cx
        loop outer2

        mov ax,y
        add ax,21
        mov tempY,ax
        mov cx,8
        outer3:
            push cx
            mov ax,x
            mov tempX,ax
            mov cx,20
            inner3:
                push cx
                mov ah,0ch
                mov al,10
                mov cx,tempX
                mov dx,tempY
                int 10h
                inc tempX
                pop cx
            loop inner3
            inc tempY
            pop cx
            loop outer3
```

Comment: define blinking?  is someone mimicing the actual hardware blinking of real 8086 video cards (i fyou accessed video ram while the scan was going across you would mess up the pixels/characters and get small blinkies here and there on the screen).  I assume that is not what you are talking about.

Comment: you have not provided a complete example, narrow it down to something with enough code we can understand where the problem might be, doesnt mean post your whole project but make a dedicated program that only demonstrates the problem, a test program...

Comment: Here is link to the video describing my problem 
[link]https://youtu.be/HvXYq5wDnRo[/link]

Comment: use paging. paint on one screen (while displaying the other) and once your paint is done, you switch. int 10h has a function (AH=5) for switching the active page

Comment: Try to find some article about how old CRT (Cathode Ray Tube) draws the picture to the screen. The signal emitted from VGA card works like that, including the reading of VRAM being done real-time in sync with the beam, i.e. if you have "black screen" in VRAM, and you turn only the few pixels ahead of beam to white, then set them back to black after it, and do that to the whole screen, the user will see "white screen" on the monitor, even if anyone else monitoring the VRAM data would see "black screen with few white pixels moving".

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42946600/4271923) may also help you to better understand the issue, if you manage to compile it (and adjust it to be .COM executable instead of bootloader sector), try it under dosbox, and change "cycles" allocated to the emulation to make the emulated machine faster/slower, to see how the situation does change with slow/fast machine.

Comment: The best "article" about how the VGA works is actually a book: Michael Abrash's *Graphics Programming Black Book*. See, for example, [this section on VGA memory accesses](http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-black-book/#the-display-adapter-cycle-eater), and [this chapter (and the entire rest of the book)](http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-black-book/#chapter-23-bones-and-sinew) on optimized VGA programming.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is called [Flickering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_(screen)#Software_artifacts). Quoting Wikipedia directly:

> For example, the practice of blanking an area directly in the frame buffer, then drawing 'on top' of it, makes it possible for the blank region to appear momentarily onscreen.

It is caused by a lack of synchronisation between your writes to the frame buffer and the video subsystem refresh cycle.
In order to maintain a consistent graphical state, you should modify the frame buffer only during a retrace, usually the [vertical retrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval) due to its longer extension.
Writing to the frame buffer while the video subsystem is reading it creates an inconsistent state because only the part of the screen below the current scan line will be updated.

The solutions to this problem all share the same outline - write the frame buffer all at once during a retrace.

The optimal solution is [Page flipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Page_flipping) and has been suggested in the comments.
It consists of switching the active frame buffer between two different area in the display adapter's memory.
Unfortunately, the VGA adapter doesn't support that for the video mode you chose<sup>1</sup> - there is only one page.

The alternative is [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) that consists in using a back buffer - as large as the frame buffer - to write in with the usual drawing primitives.
The back buffer is then presented, that is copied ([Bit blited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit)) to the frame buffer all at once during the next available retracing.

The exact writing of the software architecture is too broad, there are many ways to accomplish this and each one has a different set of required skills.
The simplest approach is to use synchronous presentation - the code performs all the graphical operations on the back buffer and then waits for the next vertical retrace to present it.
If your code is fast enough the wasted time waiting for the retrace won't matter.
Remember however that the render loop will run at the speed of the monitor refresh rate (which is usually a good thing in games because it's a free wall clock for timings).

Unfortunately, you use the BIOS services as the graphic primitives and they write in the frame buffer only (the active page actually but there's only one).

As [CodyGray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794402/avoid-blinking-flickering-when-drawing-graphics-in-8086-real-mode/43803760?noredirect=1#comment74651421_43803760) kindly reminded, the alternative is writing directly into the frame buffer - the video mode you chose is not very easy to use because it involves bit-planes. Mode 13h instead exposes the frame buffer as a continuous region of memory - pretty much like a matrix.

If you don't want to go down the road of rewriting the code that draws you can try to adjust it with some duct tape.
It's possible to tell when the monitor is in vertical retrace by testing the bit 3 of the [Input status #1 register of the VGA adapter](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/extreg.htm#3xAR) - when that bit is one the monitor is in a vertical retrace.

The idea being to wait for a vertical retrace before starting the drawing of a new frame.
This may or may not be compatible with the way you wrote your render loop - further, I've never used this hybrid approach with the BIOS calls and the vertical retrace logic.
I cannot exclude the possibility of the BIOS implementation making the wait for the retrace useless due to the way it interacts with the video subsystem.
Particularly, [CodyGray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794402/avoid-blinking-flickering-when-drawing-graphics-in-8086-real-mode/43803760?noredirect=1#comment74651421_43803760) pointed out that the BIOS calls will inexorably lead to flickering.

In order to avoid the risk of starting the frame on a near-to-end retrace, it's best to wait for a *new* retrace.

```
waitForNewVR:
 mov dx, 3dah

 ;Wait for bit 3 to be zero (not in VR).
 ;We want to detect a 0->1 transition.
_waitForEnd:
 in al, dx
 test al, 08h
jnz _waitForEnd

 ;Wait for bit 3 to be one (in VR)
_waitForNew:
 in al, dx
 test al, 08h
jz _waitForNew

 ret
```

I haven't saved the register `dx` and `ax`, you may want to add a pair of `push/pop` depending on your needs.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [Ped7g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794402/avoid-blinking-flickering-when-drawing-graphics-in-8086-real-mode/43803760?noredirect=1#comment74654117_43803760) it's possible to implement [Page flipping manipulating the hardware directly](http://www.brackeen.com/vga/unchain.html).

Comment: Everything you say is 100% correct, and good information to have, but the *real* problem here is the use of BIOS interrupt 10h, function 0Ch (draw single pixel). That's an *incredibly* slow operation, bound to produce flicker and laggy drawing. You just can't get away with using this for drawing purposes. Using page-flipping or double-buffering is one way to get around it. A better alternative is to write directly to the video buffer. Perhaps choose a video mode that facilitates this; mode 13h is a very popular choice.

Comment: The VGA actually has enough VRAM to support 4 pages for 320x200x8bpp gfx mode, but it is not possible to use that through BIOS calls, and as it "abuses" the EGA banking mechanism (IIRC) to access the additional memory, the addressing of separate pixels/pages is a bit cumbersome. It was known as "X-modes", it also allowed for 320x400 mode, or triple buffering. Of course the first thing to improve performance of OPs code is to stop using BIOS, and sync with retrace, as you suggest in your answer.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with most of your comment, I should also mention writing directly to the video buffer more explicitly. However, I'm not convinced that the problem relies on the slowness of the BIOS functions but again I've never really used them.

Comment: @Ped7g IIRC we can access all the Video RAM through the cumbersome banking but we can't make the sequencer "switch" page. Unless there is a  clever use of the bit-planes. Or maybe my first assumption is wrong and we can change the framebuffer address in the video RAM? I don't remember. Maybe I'll browse the docs later. Thanks for the elucidation.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it was possible to do the paging by changing the VRAM start, actually I'm 100% sure you can adjust VRAM start with VGA (so in modes eating up to 32k of RAM it was no-brainer), but I can't recall how the banking exactly worked on the 64k 320x200 mode, I simply got the assembly from somebody very clever, who had it already all working, never really dig into it, how it works.

Comment: @Ped7g By any chance you still have that assembly? :)

Comment: :( probably not.. and if yes, I have no idea where. But I found [nice article](http://www.brackeen.com/vga/unchain.html) ... which made me finally recall, why those modes were cumbersome, you had to switch banks to access particular columns of screen, as address 0 was used for four pixel (4 different banks), address 1 was pixels 4-7, etc... Which didn't bother us much in DOOM-like 2.5D engine, with some planning of initial data for texturing/columns drawing it was possible to draw the screen with very few bank switches, basically doing 4 pass drawing "per nth columns".

Comment: Actually the original DOOM from iD did use this mode, and it also allowed them to have "low quality" mode doubling the pixels width "for free", you just set two banks at the same time for write, and set up two pixels with single write.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this 'Flickering' issue by doing following 2 steps:

1. By adding *TimeDelay* (sleep) after drawing canvas.
2. Increasing CPU cycles of *DOSBox* to 340000000.

Thank you all for you answers.